# The fucntion is still running even thought it has called another function

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a code

```
function Search(){
    clean_map();
    $("#CS").modal('hide');
    prov = $('#Prov').val();
    map.on('zoomend', function(){
        myZoomHandler(prov);
    });

}

function myZoomHandler(prov) {
    clean_map();
    var currentZoom = map.getZoom();
    switch (currentZoom) {
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
        case 5:
        case 6:
        case 7:
            clean_map();
            mapProv(prov);
            break;
        case 8:
        case 9:
        case 10:
        case 11:
        case 12:
        case 13:
        case 14:
        case 15:
        case 16:
        case 17:
        case 18:
        case 19:
        case 20:
            clean_map();
            mapKab(prov);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

function SearchPer(){
    $('#P').modal('hide');
    clean_map();

    $.ajax({
        type : "get",
        data : { id : $('#Per').val() },
        url  : "getKab",
        dataType : "json",
        success: function(responsePer){
            GetName(responsePer, $('#Per').val());
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

If I first call the Search() function and then I call the `SearchPer()` function, all goes as expected, but if I first call `SearchPer()` and then I call `Search()` a problem will occur that is in this part of the `Search()` function:

```
map.on('zoomend', function(){
myZoomHandler(prov);
});
```

which is still running.

How to stop that part when `SearchPer()` is called?

Comment: pass a parameter to the search and only run it conditionally? Btw function is not "still running", javascript is singlethreaded, you ran SearchPer, then you ran Search, obviously the Search will run it's course regardless of the SearchPer function

Answer (score 0):

Move `zoomend` event handler out of `Search` function to the place where you initialize the map.
As whenever you run `Search` it will and a new event handler

**Update**

As I see you have defined `prov` variable somewhere in an outer scope so `zoomend` handler should be located in that scope to use it from closure.

So when the `zoomend` event triggered it will grab `prov` value that is currently there